# how to refer this element by jquery

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have td in html table like this:

I have to add or remove class `highlight` onclick of each td and based on returned data from server:

```
$("body").on("click","table#idnum tbody tr td",function(event){
 var tdid = this.id;
 var url = '...server url ..........';
 var data = {tdid:tdid};
 $.ajax({
      url,
      data: data,
      type:"POST",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
        if(data.returnval==0){
          this.removeClass('highlight');
        }else{
          this.addClass('highlight');
        }
    }
});
```

The above code was tested and found it can change the field value of concern mysql field based on get value from page (tdid) but can't add/remove class of the `td` based on return callback data ( returnval 0 or 1). I think the selector used to highlight the `td` is not right in my above code.

So please tell me how I can highlight the `td` if returnval is 1 by adding class `highlight` or remove highlighting the `td` if returnval is 0 by removing class 'highlight'?

Note: I can't use any class for `td` in order to add or remove class by selecting that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try,

```
// this will not work in success callback     
if(data.returnval==0){
    $('#'+tdid).removeClass('highlight');//use td id
}else{
    $('#'+tdid).addClass('highlight');
}
```

Comment: As the `td` obviously contains id, so it is best to select that `td` with that id to removeClass, it is simpler and easier than using context. So, according to me, this is Acceptable Answer among all, although both suggestion are good. So, I voted up the another.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems.

First, when the AJAX `success` function is called, `this` is not the same as in the original event handler function. You can use the `context:` option to `$.ajax` to pass it on:

```
context: this,
```

Second, `this` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object, so you need to use `$(this)` to use jQuery methods on it.

Comment: Best answer among these answer